# JDBC capitalizing the table in my postgres query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am running the following code

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("starting");

    org.postgresql.Driver driver = new org.postgresql.Driver();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/epcfe/", "postgres", "aap123!");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery("select * from epcfeschema.PRODUCT");

    System.out.println("done");
}
```

I keep getting `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "epcfeschema.product" does not exist`

If I create a table with the lowercase name product this works fine but I need it to work for tables with all caps. How do I keep JDBC from lowercasing my table?

Comment: It's probably PostgreSQL actually. PG is case-insensitive for schema objects by default; try putting double quotes around the table name and see if that fixes it.

Comment: *but I need it to work for tables with all caps*. Why is that so?

Comment: @Daniel: Actually it is the SQL standard that specifies case insensitivity for unquoted identifiers, not PostgreSQL; the standard also says that unquoted identifiers should be normalized to upper case but PostgreSQL normalizes to lower case.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks; I usually assume that PG is following the standard, it's interesting the cases where it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a hibernate issue, try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"PRODUCT\"")
public class Product { // ...
```

Or better yet, make your life easy: log on to postgres and rename the table!

```
ALTER TABLE "PRODUCT" rename to product;
```

(Of course, other code may depend on the cap name...)

Comment: That rename will make the table name case-insensitive, so any code that depends on the capitalized name will still work.

Comment: Yea that was my issue exactly. And there is way to much code that already depends on it being capital, so we may make it lowwercase eventually but thanks for the quick fix. :)

Comment: it at least used to be the case with Hibernate that if you used backticks around a table/column name, they were translated into the dialect-specific quotes

Answer (score 6):

You most probably created your tables using double quotes, e.g:

```
create table "PRODUCTS" (
  ...
)
```

This makes the table name case-senstive (as per the SQL Standard), and thus you need to use double quotes each time you acces the table.

```
select * from epcfeschema."PRODUCT"
```

and therefor you must use:

```
executeQuery("select * from epcfeschema.\"PRODUCT\"");
```

in your Java code (as ChssPly76 has also shown).

I would strongly recommend to re-create the tables **without** double quotes to make them case-insensitive. Then you never need them and you never have to worry about writing them im UPPER, lower or MixedCase:

When using

```
create table PRODUCTS (
  ...
)
```

all of the following statements will work:

```
select * from Products;
select * from PRODUCTS;
select * from products;
```

So you can write all of your table names in upppercase if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Quote your table names:

```
st.executeQuery("select * from epcfeschema.\"PRODUCT\"");
```

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is this was actually a little prof of concept app, I need it to work with hibernate and JPA on my real project so Normally I will not be specifying the name of the table directly.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres (and any other reasonable database) table names are case insensitive (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)).  Your problem is somewhere else - permissions, maybe?

Comment: Postgres is not a reasonable database, cause I have been working at it for a while and it is case sensitive. Again I can make a PRODUCT table and a product table at the same time....

Comment: How are you creating the table, `PRODUCT` or `"PRODUCT"`?

Comment: Cause in postgre PRODUCT <---- Capital is different from product <---- Lowwer case in postgresql. I literally just did it so yea...

Comment: Well, no.  `product` is the same as `PRODUCT`, but different from `"PRODUCT"`.  Postgres does behave the way the linked documentation describes.  Are you using `psql` for your test? If you're using a third-party tool it may be quoting all identifiers before executing the SQL.

Comment: psql CREATE TABLE "TABLEU"(
    "TABLE_VAL"   varchar(18)       NOT NULL,
    "TABLE_ID"    numeric(18, 0)
)   -------------- Also note I don't actually have control of the scripts all I can do is run them.
;