# hibernate dont find schema

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, wildfly

have wildfly 8.2.0 .

have an postgres db and an schema named 'authorization_central'.

entity mode is:

---

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")

@Entity

@Table(name = "tblusers", schema = "authorization_central")

public class User implements Serializable {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private Long id;

    private String userName;

    private String password;



    @XmlElement

    public String getUserName() {

        return userName;

    }



    public void setUserName(String userName) {

        this.userName = userName;

    }



    @XmlElement

    public String getPassword() {

        return password;

    }



    public void setPassword(String password) {

        this.password = password;

    }



    @XmlElement

    public Long getId() {

        return id;

    }



    public void setId(Long id) {

        this.id = id;

    }



    @Override

    public int hashCode() {

        int hash = 0;

        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);

        return hash;

    }



    @Override

    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set

        if (!(object instanceof User)) {

            return false;

        }

        User other = (User) object;

        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }



    @Override

    public String toString() {

        return "domain.models.User[ id=" + id + " ]";

    }



}
```

---

persistence.xml were

---

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">

  <persistence-unit name="UserPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>domain.models.User</class>

    <properties>

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"/>

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>

      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>

      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="rastin"/>-->

      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="bt_Ummah"/>-->

      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>-->

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

---

my problem is in this class:

---

```
@Transactional

public class EntityDao {



    @PersistenceContext(name = "UserPersistenceUnit")

    EntityManager entityManager;



    public void add(Object t) {

        try {

            System.out.println("start adding4.");

            if (entityManager == null) {

                System.out.println("entity manager is null.");

                entityManager = Persistence.

                        createEntityManagerFactory("UserPersistenceUnit").

                        createEntityManager();

                if (entityManager != null) {

                    System.out.println("entity manager created.");

                }

            }

//            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

            entityManager.persist(t);

//            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }



}
```

---

send me error:

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-7) Schema "AUTHORIZATION_CENTRAL" not found; SQL statement:

insert into authorization_central.tblusers (password, userName, id) values (?, ?, ?) [90079-173]

---

then created an user with name rastinuser.

created an db with name rastindb.

login with this user and db. psql -d rastindb -U rastinuser.

create schema authorization_central.

change persistence.xml this two line:

---

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/rastindb"/>

<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="rastinuser"/>
```

---

\dn command:

```
List of schemas

         Name          |   Owner   

-----------------------+------------

authorization_central | rastinuser

public                | postgres
```

---

but already problem is exists.

any one can help?

thankful.

Comment: PostgreSQL is case sensitive, can refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202919/jdbc-capitalizing-the-table-in-my-postgres-query and https://www.labkey.org/issues/home/Developer/issues/details.view?issueId=12210 and http://le-gall.net/pierrick/blog/index.php/2006/12/01/90-postgresql-and-case-sensitivity might help.

Comment: ok. but i think dont used upper case that cause error. do you see any upper case that might cause error?

Comment: The error message does show the name in UPPER case, it looks like it's used somewhere. Check the postgresql-log to get the entire query and original error message from the database. Turn on logging if you have to, it's very helpful during development.

Comment: where can used? if see above my \dn command shows lowercase of schema. in java also used only lower case. may hibernate itself convert my schema to uppercase?

Comment: @user2880318 Have you tried the solutions provided in the post provided in the comment.

Comment: it says i lowercase my table name but my table and schema is lowercase. then where must i check? now i remove schema and then it work but table in db dont created. i think hibernate use temp table. because in postgresql dont created any table tblusers. if you think must do any work i thankful tell me.